# Select a href in a list item

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have to select a `a href` inside a list and exclude it from specific styling. Could not make it work with `nth-child` and tailwind.

```css
<ul>
    <li><a href="/" class="">linka</a></li>
    <li><a href="/" class="">linkb</a></li>
    <li><a href="/" class="">linkc</a></li>
    <li><a href="/" class="">linkd</a></li>
    <li><a href="/" class="">linke</a></li>
    <li><a href="/" class="">linkf</a></li>
</ul>
```

So I want to apply styling to all links, a to f, but excluding b and d. Again, I have to target the `a href` and give it a class. Tailwinds `arbitrary variants` seems the way to go.

Came up with this:

```
ul > li > a {
@apply [&>*:not(:nth-child(-n+1))]:block;
}
```

But that did not work.

See above. See above.

Comment: Did you try `li:not(:nth-child(2), :nth-child(4)) a` ? It certainly looks like it should work ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/15wqhpd2/)), though I don't know if Tailwind might cause problems with that selector.

Comment: @David Thomas - WOW, yes, works perfectly. Feeling sad now that I could not come up with this. But thanks a lot.

Comment: @David Thomas - oops, problems? Well, dont see any for now. But like what problems?

Comment: I don't anticipate any, but I've only ever really played with Tailwind, so I don't know if it might have issues (it seems highly unlikely though).

Comment: @David Thomas, OK, thanks. I am good with it. If you can put your solution in an answer then I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, after verifying the functionality in the comments:

```css
li {
  padding-block: 0.5rem;
  padding-inline: 1rem;
}

a {
  display: block;
}

/* here we select all <a> elements that are within
   <li> elements that are NOT :nth-child(2) or
   :nth-child(4) of among their siblings: */
li:not(:nth-child(2), :nth-child(4)) a {
  background-color: hsl(300deg 80% 80% / 0.7);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="/" class="">linka</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="">linkb</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="">linkc</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="">linkd</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="">linke</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="">linkf</a></li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/15wqhpd2/).